# How to use a class member function as defualt value

Tags: c++

I have this class

```
class InventoryManagement
{
public:
    typedef void(InventoryManagement::*Action)(void);
    typedef void(InventoryManagement::*ActionWithReturn)(InventoryItem);

    void Initialize(int inventoryQty, int maxQty, ActionWithReturn onAdd = nullptr , Action onMaxQtyReach = nullptr, Action onQtyReset = nullptr, Action onSideChnage = nullptr);

    Action getStrategyOnMaxQtyReach();
    Action getStrategyOnQtyReset();
    Action getStrategyOnSideChange();
    ActionWithReturn getOnAdd();

private:

    // Private Functions Data members
    ActionWithReturn m_onAdd;
    Action m_OnSideChange;
    Action m_OnQtyReset;
    Action m_OnMaxQtyReach;


    // Default Function 
    void OnAddDefault(InventoryItem item) { }
    void OnMaxQtyReachDefault() { }
    void OnQtyResetDefault() { }
    void OnSideChangeDefault() { }
};
```

The function `Initialize` sets the data members of type `Action`.
I created default actions that do noting and I want to pass them as default arguments. If the user doesn't send any function pointer to `Initialize` then those functions will be set.

The signature of the function is:

```
void Initialize(int inventoryQty, int maxQty, ActionWithReturn onAdd = nullptr , Action onMaxQtyReach = nullptr, Action onQtyReset = nullptr, Action onSideChnage = nullptr);
```

I tried
`void Initialize(int inventoryQty, int maxQty, ActionWithReturn onAdd = InventoryManagement::OnAddDefault , Action onMaxQtyReach = nullptr, Action onQtyReset = nullptr, Action onSideChnage = nullptr);`
instead of `nullptr`, but the compiler emitted *"Call to non-static member function without an object argument"*.

Comment: `function Initialize then thosw function will set.` wat? `InventoryManagement::*OnAddDefault` what is `InventoryManagement` and `OnAddDefault`? Provide [mcve].

Comment: Can `InventoryManagement::OnAddDefault` be `static`?

Comment: @yaodav Please provide a minimal complete code.

Comment: the error just means what it says: You are trying to call a non-static method without an object. However, the actual source of the error message you didnt post. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @VladfromMoscow i added the class def

Comment: Please also show the code that results in the error

Comment: It's great that you answer and do what we ask. However you need to [edit] your question to include the information. Comments are for requesting clarification, the question must contain all the relevant information.

Comment: Consider a "named ctor".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is `&InventoryManagement::OnAddDefault`:

```
void Initialize(
    int inventoryQty,
    int maxQty,
    ActionWithReturn onAdd = &InventoryManagement::OnAddDefault, // <-- 
    Action onMaxQtyReach = nullptr,
    //... etc
)
```

On a side node, I encourage you to consider using constructors instead of initialize methods.

Comment: thank you, it works, i know that the right way is in the constructor but a limitation that i have

Comment: @yaodav     Try adding, "InventoryManagement() = delete;" to your class.  If you believe that not having a ctor is "a limitation that i have", I think you have not yet eliminated the 'ctor' per that limitation.

Comment: @2785528 when I wrote that I have a limitation it was about the doing the initialization in the CTOR and not int the function Initialize,